# Error while making connection using TCP Client

Tags: c#, sockets, c#-4.0, tcpclient, socketexception

I am trying to make connection with remote system in the network using C#. then the program is throwing the following exception

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.1.42:8000

```
private void Start_Sending_Video_Conference(string remote_IP,int port_number)
{
    try
    {
        ms = new MemoryStream();// Store it in Binary Array as 
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] arrImage = ms.GetBuffer();
        myclient = new TcpClient (remote_IP,port_number);//Connecting with server
        myns = myclient.GetStream ();
        mysw = new BinaryWriter (myns);
        mysw.Write(arrImage);//send the stream to above address
        ms.Flush();
        mysw.Flush();
        myns.Flush();
        ms.Close();
        mysw.Close ();
        myns.Close ();
        myclient.Close ();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Capturing.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Video Conference Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure something is listening on the other end? In this case, it appears that your local server is actually denying the request. Please confirm that the server is running, the TCPServer is listening, and that the machine the server is running from (if it's locally, this shouldn't be a problem) is setup to allow incoming packets from the LAN.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the usual suspects:

1. Is server application really running
2. Does it really listen on port 8000?
3. Does firewall on client computer allow outgoing traffic on port 8000?
4. Does firewall on server computer allow incoming traffic on port 8000?

Answer (score 0):

If the solutions above didn't work, then the problem is probably in the Server code.
you may have used an instance of TcpListener to listen to the specified port, but which IpAddress did you pass to the constructor?
If you wrote the following code:

```
mylistener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 8000);
```

It will result in that error.
This happens because The Loopback dosen't make the listener listen to all the network interfaces, but only the requests coming from the localhost (127.0.0.1).

Use this code instead

```
mylistener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
```